# Operações com campos calculados de uma view mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde,

Eu tenho uma view onde existem vários campos onde possuo diversos cálculos, e o resultado destes cálculos gostaria de utilizar em outros campos desta mesma view.

Um exemplo:

```
    select (tab1.campo1+tab1.campo2)/tab1.campo1-1 as margem, 
margem * 100 as %margem from tab1;
```

Sendo que o calculo de "%margem" é feito com o resultado do cálculo anterior.

Tentei utilizar desta maneira mas ocorre o erro abaixo:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'comissão liquida' in 'field list'

Comment: Como você está fazendo isso ? Posta sua Query. Mas já deu pra ver que o nome da coluna **comissão liquida** não existe. Como sugestão, evite nome de campos com acentos, espaços e afins.

Comment: Edita esse título pelo amor de deus, parece que você tá gritando conosco.

Comment: É só não responder chefe

Comment: O erro que aparece é  Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'nome da coluna que uso' in 'field list'

Comment: select (tab1.campo1+tab1.campo2)/tab1.campo1-1 as margem, 
(tab1.campo1+tab1.campo2)/tab1.campo1-1 * 100 as %margem from tab1;

Comment: Sim, na view que tenho hoje está sendo de maneira semelhante. O problema é que o calculo que usei como exemplo é muito mais simples do que uso no código original. Eu gostaria de utilizar o resultado de uma coluna para calcular uma outra.

Comment: `%margem` não é um *alias* válido, tente com `percentual_margem`.

Comment: ok, select (tab1.campo1+tab1.campo2)/tab1.campo1-1 as margem, 
margem * 100 as margem_percentual from tab1; Da mesma maneira não funciona